# How to delete autoscaling groups with aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to write a bash script that will delete my EC2 instances and the auto scaling group that launched them:

```
EC2s=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region=eu-west-3 \
  --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*-my-dev-eu-west-3" \
  --query "Reservations[].Instances[].InstanceId" \
  --output text)
for id in $EC2s
do
  aws ec2 terminate-instances --region=eu-west-3 --instance-ids $id
done
aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --region eu-west-3 \
  --auto-scaling-group-name my-asg-dev-eu-west-3
```

But it fails with this error:

```
An error occurred (ResourceInUse) when calling the DeleteAutoScalingGroup operation:
You cannot delete an AutoScalingGroup while there are instances or pending Spot 
instance request(s) still in the group.
```

There is no issue if I use the AWS console to do the same thing.  Why does the aws cli prevent me from deleting the ASG if I have terminated all the instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you really want to do this with CLI, you may first want to use `aws autoscaling suspend-processes` command to prevent ASG from creating new instances. Then use `aws ec2 terminate-instances` like you are doing. Then use `aws ec2 wait instance-terminated` command and pass instance ids. Once all that is done, you should be able use `aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group`

Answer (score 2):

`aws ec2 terminate-instances` will return before the instances have finished terminating (which could take several minutes).

I highly recommend using something like CloudFormation or Terraform for this sort of thing instead of the AWS CLI tool.

Comment: Ironically I am writing this script to clean up after a failed terraform runs.  I want to get my environment back to pre-terraform state.

Comment: That's what `terraform destroy` is for. Why are you trying to reinvent that?

Comment: I work in a development environment where people make changes to the AWS infrastructure in the AWS console and the state file gets out of sync, so I just want to wipe everything out and start from scratch.

Comment: There are already tools for doing that as well: https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke

Answer (score 0):

You can force delete the ASG with active spot instance requests with AWS cli:

```
aws autoscaling delete-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name Your-ASG-Name --force-delete
```